# Given that $−5x^3−4xy−2y^2=1$. What is the change in y with respect to x.

Tags: calculus

From my last test.

> Given that $-5x^3-4xy-2y^2 = 1$. Determine the change in $y$ with respect to $x$.
>
> A. $-\dfrac{-15x^2-4}{-4-4y}$
> B. $- \dfrac{-15x^2-4y}{-4-4y}$
> C. $- \dfrac{-15x^2-4}{-4x-4y}$
> D. $- \dfrac{-10x-4y}{-4x-2} $
> E. $- \dfrac{-15x^2-4y}{-4x-4y}$

I got the answer E, but the teacher said it was A.

My Work (*tell me my mistake*)

find $dx$ and $dy$ at the same time.

$dx(-15x^2-4y)-dy(4x+4y)=0$

$dx(-15x^2-4y)=dy(4x+4y)$

$\dfrac{dx(-15x^2-4y)}{dy(4x+4y)} = 1$

$\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right) \dfrac{dx(-15x^2-4y)}{dy(4x+4y)} = 1\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)$

$ \dfrac{-15x^2-4y}{4x+4y} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$ which is the same as **E**.

Comment: @julianKueshammer Did you find any mistakes?

Comment: It's not the same as $E$, it has a different sign in the denominator. However, it would be the same as $E$ if you hadn't switched that sign along the way.

Comment: @joriki, Where did I switch the sign?

Comment: Going from the first to the second line you did some silly error

Comment: @MaoYiyi I just made the title more descriptive.

Comment: @ Mao Yiyi: Now it's okay

Comment: How could **A** be the answer?

Comment: I guess the simple solution to that question is that A is not the answer but E is.
You can cross check that at: [Wolfram|Alpha $-5x^3+-4xy-2y^2=1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-5x^3+-4x*y-2y^2=1) in section implicit derrivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a relation $F(x,y)=0$ in which $y$ is a function of $x$ then : $$y'=\frac{-F_x}{F_y}$$
Here, $F(x,y)=-5x^3-4xy-2y^2-1=0$ and $F_x=-15x^2-4y, F_y=-4x-4y$. So, $$y'=\frac{15x^2+4y}{-4(x+y)}$$

Comment: F(x,y) = 1, not zero. ??? COuld you explain a bit more?

Comment: How does one get that formula.  I tried searching for the LaTeX of your answer, but I didn't find anything that would explain it.

Comment: @MaoYiyi: Let $F(x,y)=0$. Now take the differential of it, considering that $y$ is a function of $x$. Then you get $$F_x(x,y)\frac{dx}{dx}+F_y(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ Rearranging the last equation, we have above.

Comment: @amWhy: More than expected are yours now Amy. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 0):

$$-5x^3-4xy-2y^2 = 1$$
$$-15x^2-4y-4xy'-4yy'=0$$
$$4xy'+4yy'=-15x^2-4y$$
$$y'(4x+4y)=-15x^2-4y$$
$$y'=\frac{-15x^2-4y}{4x+4y}$$

Comment: This is what just Mao has given , it's nothing new!

Comment: that  is right answer